# Route traffic between interfaces on same device ( wlan0 to usb0 )

Tags: iptables, routing, ethernet, interface, traffic

I have a usb0 interface with 10.0.0.1 ip with a router on 10.0.0.2 and unaccessible to internet. I also have a wifi adapter on wlan0 with 192.168.0.3 connected to my router at 192.168.0.1 (this is connected to internet). How can relay traffic from my wlan0 to my usb0 interface? The two interfaces exist on the same device.

I've tried using iptables with ip forwarding enabled:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o usb0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o usb0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

If I try

```
ping -I wlan0 google.com
```

then I get a response but if I just try

```
ping google.com
```

then I don't get any reply back.

Preferably I would like the `wlan0` traffic to route to `usb0`, but if I could somehow set `wlan0` as my primary interface (and use `pacman -Syu` on it, for example) , that would work as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to **relay** traffic from 10.0.0.*/24 to 192.168.0.1, (i.e., have two subnets), or do you want to **NAT** ("network address translation"), and pretend to your router at 192.168.0.1 that everything that's coming from 10.0.0.*/24 is coming from 192.168.0.3? In the latter case, only MASQUERADE on the interface to the router (`wlan0`), not on both.

Comment: thanks for your response. yes I want to NAT the traffic from my wifi adapter on wlan0 to my machine which has another network on usb0. The reason is that usb0 is an internal network which is connected to my ipad, but is unable to reach the internet because of apple sandboxing issues. So I thought it might be possible to route my external wifi adapter traffic to my linux machine. The thing is I still need usb0 as i'm sshing through this interface to termius. Is this possible and if so how? thanks again.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the important information that you are on iOS to add.

Answer (score 1):

> yes I want to NAT the traffic from my wifi adapter on wlan0 to my machine which has another network on usb0.

You normally phrase this the other way round: you want to NAT the traffic from `usb0` ("internal interface") when it leaves on `wlan0` towards rest of the world.

So only masquerade on the external interface `wlan0`:

```
EXTIF=wlan0
INTIF=usb0
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

The last line is important, and does the actual NAT. The rest only filters, and makes sure nothing funny gets forwarded into the internal network (`usb0`).

(Make sure to drop all rules first before doing the above, if they are still active).

Comment: I think your amended script might work on a traditional setup, but my setup is on iOS which is ridicuously anal about forwarding traffic. Searched around and, unless I'm missing something, there doesn't seem to be a way to route traffic from iOS wifi to an RNDIS ethernet gadget (which happens to by the usb0) into my arch box.
Regardless, I managed to make some sort of compromise by playing with dhcpcd.conf. Specifically, I commented out noipv4ll and got rid of static usb0 settings there. Then I flushed dhcpcd -k and then sudo dhcpcd. Rebooted with wifi adapter and ping worked.

Comment: You still shouldn't do NAT on both interfaces. I have not seen what you've done in detail, and I don't have iOS, so I cannot comment on what blocked it before you changed the settings. Unless iOS modifies the Linux kernel in ridiculous ways, being an RNDIS ethernet gadget shouldn't make any difference, at all.